# Get all public files with wget

Tags: http, ports

There's a host and a port(with TCP support) on which http service is running. Simple

```
wget host:port
```

doesn't return anything. Is  it possible to get a list of all accessible files(html or txt) on that host(and the given port) which can be viewed?

Maybe there's some pattern like

`wget host:port/*.[html|txt]` or something

Answer (score 3):

This command …

```
$ wget --spider DOWNLOAD-URL
```

will check if `DOWNLOAD-URL` is available to download.

You can check this link for more options on `wget`: [Ultimate wget guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/). Also check the manual for `wget` you may more interesting options.

Comment: +1 for the link, but the question is about scanning the tree for the ALL public files which can be downloaded - the definite URIs are not known

Comment: If there is no index, and you don't have list permissions on the host, it won't be possible. Otherwise, you want Section 10 (Mirror mode) in the linked guide.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Google Search with the `site:` operator.

Example: I want to find out the URLs that are hosted on `nlp.stanford.edu:8080`.  Solution: I go to Google Search and enter the search term `site:nlp.stanford.edu:8080`.  Then, I use wget to begin spidering from all of the URLs found in the search results.